# Spectre: Problem with Understanding POC - Reading data from cache

Tags: exploit, exploit-development, code-review, meltdown, spectre

I understand the vulnerability (Spectre) and, in theory, what the [PoC](https://gist.github.com/ErikAugust/724d4a969fb2c6ae1bbd7b2a9e3d4bb6) does. But I do not understand the part of the [PoC](https://gist.github.com/ErikAugust/724d4a969fb2c6ae1bbd7b2a9e3d4bb6), when it reads or identifys the data from the cache, between the lines 86 - 108. I know that the PoC is reading the data from the cache by measuring the time of reading from *addr (at l. 90), but what exercise has `results[]` and why `mix_i` hits the cache when it represents the byte at the address of the cache hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what exercise has results[]

It is not an exact art. The cache may be hit for an index which is not the one hit by victim_function. The threshold might lead to borderline results.

So the code runs the attack 999 times and increments results[mix_i] when it thinks there is a cache hit. It then selects the result with the highest result value (most expected cache hits) and assumes that is the correct value for the victim byte.

> why mix_i hits the cache when it represents the byte at the address of the cache hit?

mix_i is just a way of shuffling i.

```
for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    mix_i = ((i * 167) + 13) & 255;
    ...
}
```

The above results in mix_i being initialised as each value between 0-255 once only but not in the order 0,1,2,3 (as i is). This is done for the reason stated in the comments - to [prevent stride prediction](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~amrm/slides/amrm_structure/pta/tsld049.htm);

Comment: So the offset of one byte in the cache is equivalent to the value of the byte in the cache, right?

Comment: @user104787 - Yes - because the privileged byte was used to index into the array in the speculatively executed instructions.